# Where can I find literature regarding cardinal invariants of a function space C(X,Y) endowed with the Uniform or Fine topology?

Tags: general-topology, function-spaces

I am working on Function Spaces as a topological space. I want to get a sample paper which studies the cardinal invariants on the function space C(X,Y) rather than on C(X).

Comment: Can you recall what the cardinal invariants are here? And what means C(X).v?

Comment: McCoy and Ntantu have a booklet (quite old) in such matters.

Comment: I googled it (they were old lecture notes I've read while doing a PhD) see [the publisher's link](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540193029). Some further links can also be found on that page.

Comment: This book has literature regarding cardinal invariants of $C(X)$ only. I want to have it for a more general space $C(X, Y)$.